# No matching authentication protocol exception while connecting to Oracle 12c from Websphere

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am getting the following exception when i am trying to bring up my server wepshere 7.Can some one help me out in resoving this if some thing needs to be added and where?(Newly migrated to Oracle 12c). Attached the exception screen shot

Answer (score 2):

Websphere 7 is a pretty old release (2008), and I doubt anyone has tested it with 12c. Most probably the client is using a very old protocol. The allowed protocols can be set in the sqlnet.ora with the parameter `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT`. Check the Oracle documentation for the allowed settings.